# Bing map Pushpin to handle gridview check box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, bing-maps

I am stuck at a point where I want to be able to interact from the map, by clicking on the pushpin, or an Event handled by the info box which can check or uncheck the Selected Row in my  Gridview which is on the same page.  I am using Ajax, Asp.net and at this point I am handling the data on the map by using GEORss from the database.

Another question: is there a possibility to create dynamic GEORSS xml files, which can be accessed by bing, by just a click. I believe Stored Procedures is one of the methods, but further that, how do I make it accessible to Bing maps as the Xml file needs to be hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this once before, by attaching some jquery that to the click event that simply adds som css to the gridview cell marked with the the id.

```
$('idOfGridview').css('hilightCell');
```

before that call I made sure that all had their background set to white.